# 'HY000', 'The SQL contains 31 parameter markers, but 32 parameters were supplied' with access mdb file

Tags: python, mysql, database, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm copying from MySQL to MDB and I'm coming up against a strange issue. I have a query

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE SIGN_INVENTORY SET DISTRICT=?, COUNTY=?, CITY=?, ROUTE_ID=?, NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE=?, INSP_FREQ=?, GPS_LATITUDE=?, GPS_LONGITUDE=?,
FABRICATOR=?, CONTRACTOR=?, DATE_ERECTED=?, DATE_LAST_MODIFIED=?, BRIDGE_ID=?, STATE_PLANE=?, BEGIN_NODE=?, BEGIN_OFFSET=?,
SPAN_LENGTH=?, NUMBER_SIGNS=?, TOTAL_SIGN_AREA=?, WALKWAY_LENGTH=?, STRUCTURE_TYPE=?, MESSAGE_TYPE=?, VMS_TYPE=?, MATERIAL_TYPE=?,
CHORD_TYPE=?, POLE_TYPE=?, FOUNDATION_TYPE=?, LAST_INSPECTOR=?, LMOD_USERID=?, LMOD_DATE=?, LMOD_TIME=?
WHERE STRUCTURE_NUMBER=?""", (row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10],
                              row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20],
                              row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29], row[30],
                              row[31], row[0]))
```

I'm getting the error

```
'HY000', 'The SQL contains 31 parameter markers, but 32 parameters were supplied'
```

Now if I remove the last row[0] I get

```
'HY000', 'The SQL contains 32 parameter markers, but 31 parameters were supplied'
```

The columns in both databases are exactly the same. I'm doing very similar queries in multiple other places and they work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In MySQL date fields are stored like

```
datetime.datetime(2002, 7, 22, 0, 0)
```

this was causing the parameter count to break. I needed to cast the values to char like so

```
cast(NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE as char)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy nothing need to do just pass 31 parameters not more then that

see 1 to 31 is total 31 after that u are passing row[0] and that makes the total parameter count is 32, that's why u are getting that error.

Comment: As you can see in my OP, removing it just flips the count. The error isn't actually related to the parameter count - it's related to how MySQL stores date fields.